# Actualización de formula en excel

Tags: visual

alguien sabe como se puede actualizar la referencia de una fórmula.

Por ejemplo, tengo en la celda A1 la fórmula:
=H5

Pero si yo borro la fila 5 de la hoja, se borra la H5, en teoría, porque sigue existiendo H5 con la nueva fila que se movió hacia arriba

Cómo hago para que en A1, no me notifique ERROR DE REFERENCIA, y se actualice a la nueva celda H5?

Sé que por código se puede hacer, pero son muchas y se vuelve muy lento.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.